# stepToTap DELETE key on ipad keyboard with KIF

Tags: ios, ipad, integration-testing, kif-framework

Is there a way to simulate deleting a character when in a UITextField.

I have tried this while the keyboard is visible

```
[scenario addStep:[KIFTestStep stepToTapViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"Delete" traits:UIAccessibilityTraitKeyboardKey]];
```

but am coming up short?

Comment: Actually, your code works fine for me. Maybe your text field doesn't have focus? Could you post the other steps in your scenario?

Comment: Have you set accessibility label of the UITextField correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to KIF as well but you might try using tapping the point where the Delete key is located.

```
[KIFTestStep stepToTapScreenAtPoint:CGPointMake(300,389)];
```

You could then abstract that into your own step definition called `[KIFTestStep stepToTapDeleteKey];`

Comment: Very fragile approach. Will break if orientation changes, device changes or display resolution changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the function to always clear the textField instead of appending it as explained in this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/kif-framework/flE1fUepTis).  Just replace the function with the one shown in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Found a new answer using KIF testing

Once you run the command to tap the textfield which brings up the numpad you can do this:

```
tester.tapViewWithAccessibilityLabel("Delete")
```

This will delete one spot in that textfield assuming you selected it with the previous command.

Or you could hold the delete key to delete everything in that field

```
tester.longPressViewWithAccessibilityLabel("Delete", duration: 3.6)
```